# Value is Null in controller when passed from JSP page

Tags: spring-mvc, jsp

I am trying to send the value of State from JSP page to my controller, when I alert I'm able to get the state Value and also in the context path but when it comes to controller the value is null , made the required as false but still unable to get the value.

**JSP**

```
$("[id='states']").on("change", function(e){
    var state= $("#states").val();
     alert(state);
    window.location.replace("${pageContext.request.contextPath}" + "/rates/status?"+status);
```

**Controller**

```
  @RequestMapping(value = Admin.STATE_GET, method = RequestMethod.GET)    
    public ModelAndView getstatus(
            /* @RequestParam("state")String state, */
            //@RequestParam(value = "state") String state,
            //@RequestParam(value="state", required = false) String state,
            @RequestParam(required = false, value = "state") String state,
            @ModelAttribute("stateList") StatesVO stateList,                 
            BindingResult results, HttpServletRequest req){
            System.out.println("state==="+state);
```

Tried different ways to get the value in controller but still getting NULL. Please assist.

Comment: Why ModelAttribute for recieving single value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing equal operator `(=)` so add in URL like below.

```
window.location.replace("${pageContext.request.contextPath}" + "/rates/states?state="+state);
```

Comment: Could you please accept the answer as it worked for you... thanks

Comment: sure, how do i do? Also, can u give me points if u can for posting question where  I get points for  research done